# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup' - can't run development server

Tags: python, django

I was running the development server, modifying some css, not doing anything unusual when suddenly the server crashes.

I tried running it again and was greeted with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/david/.virtualenvs/sikumim/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setup'
```

I'm pretty confused seeing as I didn't actually do anything that seems to have caused this, google search didn't get me far, basically I'm stumped.

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you have multiple versions of django installed (perhaps one system-wide, and one in a virtualenv)?

That error would be caused by calling a `manage.py` created from a newer (>= 1.7) django version with an older django package on the python path.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted virtualenv, recreated installed requirements and everything seems to work.

If anyone has any insight into what the hell happened I would love to hear it.

problem solved I guess